# < Property X does not exist on type of import("...") > in case of modules

Tags: typescript

One module exports function "A". Second module exports functions "A" and "B".

At first I need to create a map array, like this:

```
const map = [
  {
    name: 'A',
    data: moduleA
  },
  {
    name: 'B',
    data: moduleB
  }
];
```

I'm trying to run functions "A" and "B" in a cycle like this:

```
item.data.A('some data');

if(item.data && item.data.B)    // here's error
    item.data.B('other data');
```

But getting this weird error:

> Property 'B' does not exist on type 'typeof import(".../moduleA")'

How to get rid if this error? And why does it even happen?

[Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-joliot-qyihx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)